# Google script constantly asks for authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization

I have developed a Google Apps Script which I am deploying as a web app on a Classic site.  The app always executes as myself, even when others visit the site.  The script pulls from a spreadsheet that I own to create an HTML table.

Everything works fine EXCEPT that the app consistently fails to execute because it is asking for permission to manage my spreadsheets.

According to Google's documentation on script authorization, the app should ask for permission whenever the code is changed.  So, when I make changes to the code, I run the doGet method and authorize the app to access my files.

HOWEVER, even when I don't change the code, after a while the app will fail to execute and require me to go in, run a method, and give permission again.

So, my app is effectively broken because I need to go in and authorize it every few hours, and thus cannot deploy it for long-term use.

I've seen that someone had a similar issue, but the reason for their problem was that they had reached the limit of the number of scripts they could have authorized at once.  I only have the one script, so this shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Sounds like something else in your environment is revoking permissions you've given out. Are you in a Gsuite domain, etc, where an admin may be seeing an unauthorized / unverified app accessing domain resources and then revoking permission.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have deployed the live version ending with /exec and not the development version that ends with /dev